# How to refresh token and retry request on 401 error using Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, httprequest, hybrid-mobile-app, http-status-code-401

I try to refresh token and retry request on 401 error, but can not understand how to do it by right way

Answer (score 0):

This is a recreation from what I remember so there can be typo and small errors maybe.

I hope you get an idea what I am trying to do here.

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class APIUtility {
 Uri uri;
 String path, method;
 var body;
 var headers;

 APIUtility({ @required this.path, @required this.method, this.body}) {
  this.uri = Uri.parse("http://localhost:4000/api/${this.path}");
  this.headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'};
 }

 Future request({ bool useToken = true }) async {
   http.Response response;
   if ( useToken ) { this.header['token'] = await getAccessToken(); }

   try {
    response = await // call api with http package with correct path, method and body
    if ( useToken && response.statusCode == 401 ) return await _refreshTokenAndRequest();
    else return jsonDecode(response.data);
   }
   catch (e) {
    print(e);
    return null;
   }

 }

 _refreshTokenAndRequest() async {
   String accessToken = await getAccessToken();
   String refreshToken = await getRefreshToken();
   var body = {'access_token': accessToken, 'refresh_token': refreshToken};
   http.Response response = await http.post("${this.baseUrl}/api/auth/refresh", body: body);
   if (response.statusCode == 200 || response.statusCode == 201) {
      saveAccessToken(response.body['access_token']); 
      saveRefreshToken(response.body['refresh_token']);
      return await request();
   } else {
     // Logout user from app
     // Delete all database, token and all user info and show login screen;
     return null;
   }
 }

}
```